# Flask SQLAlchemy: How to extend the base Model class?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In Flask/SQLAlchemy, we use the `Model` class from `flask_sqlalchemy` instead of from `sqlalchemy`, like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Foo(db.Model):
    bar = db.Column(db.String)
```

I have a function that I add to every Model I define. I want to extend some base class and add the function there so I don't have to repeat myself. With normal SQLAlchemy we can extend the declarative base class to do this. How can we achieve this in `flask_sqlalchemy` ?

Extending from the `db.Model` class doesn't work without raising:

> InvalidRequestError: Class  does not have a **table** or **tablename** specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix the error by setting `__abstract__ = True`.  I modified your example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Foo(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    bar = db.Column(db.String)
```

`__abstract__` is described in [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract).  Alternatively, you can use a [mixin class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#declarative-mixins).

Requiring more code, you can also override the declarative base class by subclassing `SQLAlchemy` and overriding its `make_declarative_base()` method.  Example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, Model, _BoundDeclarativeMeta, _QueryProperty
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

app = Flask(__name__)

class MyModel(Model):
    ...

class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def make_declarative_base(self, metadata=None):
        base = declarative_base(cls=MyModel, name='MyModel',
                                metadata=metadata,
                                metaclass=_BoundDeclarativeMeta)
        base.query = _QueryProperty(self)
        return base

db = MySQLAlchemy(app)
```

and then subclassing `db.Model` "as usual".

Comment: I added another way to do this. I'm not much of an SQLAlchemy expert, so I hope this is correct as well.

Comment: That is interesting - cool. I will stick with the first way for now.